# How to mock SpringUtils.getBean("beanName") by Mockito.mockStatic(SpringUtils.class)

Tags: mockito

when I try to mock a static method likes SpringUtils.getBean("BeanName") with Mockito 3.7.7, , and I got a NullPointerException of applicationContext, and the getBean("BeanName") method seems still been executed, Here is my code as fellow:

```
public  class SpringUtils implements  ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        SpringUtils.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getBean(String name) throws BeansException {
        // NullPointerException here
        return (T) applicationContext.getBean(name);
    }
}
```

And this is where I use SpringUtils:

```
public class Aaa{
    public Integer getSpringBean(){
        RedisTemplate<String,Object> redisTemplate = SpringUtils.getBean("abc");
        System.out.println(1234);
        return 5;
    }
}
```

The test code as fellow:

```
@Test
public void test(){

        Aaa a = new Aaa();
        try (MockedStatic<SpringUtils> theMock1 = Mockito.mockStatic(SpringUtils.class)) {
            theMock1.when(()->SpringUtils.getBean(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Mockito.mock(RedisTemplate.class));
        }
        Integer x = a.getSpringBean();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

then I got a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.labs.common.idgenerator.utils.SpringUtils.getBean(SpringUtils.java:42)
    at com.labs.common.idgenerator.config.Aaa.getSpringBean(Aaa.java:24)
```

so, how to mock SpringUtils.getBean("beanName") with mockito correctly?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a try-with-resources block to manage your MockedStatic.
This means that the MockedStatic object is created when entering this block, but when the block is exited the resource is automatically closed.

Take a look at [MockedStatic.close()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.3/org/mockito/MockedStatic.html#close--)

> Releases this static mock and throws a MockitoException if closed already.

All interactions with stubbed static method must be done when MockedStatic is still active - in the scope of try-with-resources block:

```
try (MockedStatic<SpringUtils> theMock1 = Mockito.mockStatic(SpringUtils.class)) {
    theMock1.when(()->SpringUtils.getBean(Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenReturn(Mockito.mock(RedisTemplate.class));
    Aaa a = new Aaa();
    Integer x = a.getSpringBean();
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the code as fellow, and it works fine, but I'm not quite sure about that it's a good solution:

```
    @Test
    public void test(){
        CodeRuleConfig config = null;
        try(
            //spring utils
            MockedStatic spring = mockStatic(SpringUtils.class);
            //config center, depends on SpringUtils
            MockedStatic gaea = mockStatic(GaeaUtils.class);
            //RedisUtils, depends on SpringUtils
            MockedStatic redis = mockStatic(RedisUtils.class)
        ){
            spring.when(()->SpringUtils.getBean(Environment.class)).thenReturn(MockData.mockEnv());
            gaea.when(()->GaeaUtils.getCodeRuleConfig(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(MockData.getCodeRuleConfig());
            redis.when(()->RedisUtils.hIncrBy(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(),Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(999L);
                    System.out.println(IdGenerator.getInstance().nextCode("orderNo"));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks good, but to my eyes your object only depends on RedisUtils - SpringUtils is an internal implementation of RedisUtils, if you mock RedisUtils, there is no need to mock its dependencies